# How to retrieve an image from an Excel file using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, excel, image, cell, xlsx

I am having trouble getting images from Excel file.
Is there anyone who can do it in Node.js?

I need any library in Node.js that can return back images from cells in an Excel file.

Comment: Exceljs is a good choice

Comment: But how can I do that from Exceljs?

Comment: I recommend copy pasting your post into chat gpt. It will provide a code example.